# Process Management Library

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, process

I am working on an OLAP application, WCF + Silverlight clients (up to 100 concurrent users). Unfortunately from time to time, a specific service call goes crazy (although it is perfectly valid, just too complex) and occasionally (once a month) brings the whole server down (by consuming all CPU).

A solution would involve killing user request or even the whole user session which is not a big deal for us from the business perspective - recovering/restarting the whole application is.

The idea of isolating user sessions into separate processes is very tempting: CPU/memory throttling and clean resource disposal (not like Thread.Abort) - if modern browsers can do this just for web pages, maybe it's time to do this on servers. We just want to evaluate this concept and see pros and cons in our particular scenario.

Hence the questions:

1. Is there already an existing library/framework which will be useful for managing processes (like pre-spawning/reusing processes, throttling, kill after timeout)?
2. Are there any "best practices" or guidelines how to create such architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem with my WCF services they too serve more than 100 clients..
and problem which i discovered using IIS logs (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR)
I found my problem in Application Pool Recycle timeout on IIS setting.
Application pool was getting restarted every 48 hours and which was causing issues with already subscribed clients.
So i would suggest 
1. Analyze the http error logs and IIS logs which will give more information about all the application pools status if any gets shutdown or recycled.
2. If application pool crashes then Setup for Windbg and attach the process set the correct source file path. It will tell you the location if any exceptions are occurring.

Comment: Thank you Sumeet. But in my case the problem is that no exception occurs. The system (CPU) is just choked by a complex action executed by a single user.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you are worried about 100% CPU Usage?.To solve 100% CPU Problem try to put a Thread.sleep(1) on the loops or constant running code that improves a lot. i was having close to 90 threads constantly running for communication with devices and had 100% CPU utilization after 1 day then i put Thread.sleep(6) and it reduced to 30%.